# Read CSV into array

Tags: csv, julia

In Julia, using [`CSV.jl`](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/), it is possible to read a DataFrame from a `.csv` file:

```
using CSV

df = CSV.read("data.csv", delim=",")
```

However, how can I instead read a CSV file into an `Vector{Float64}` data type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `DelimitedFiles` module from stdlib:

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> s = """
       1,2,3
       4,5,6
       7,8,9"""
"1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9"

julia> b = IOBuffer(s)
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=false, seekable=true, append=false, size=17, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> readdlm(b, ',', Float64)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0
 4.0  5.0  6.0
 7.0  8.0  9.0
```

I am showing you the example reading from `IOBuffer` to be fully reproducible, but you can also read data from file. In the docstring of `readdlm` you can find more details about the available options.

Notice that you will get `Matrix{Float64}` not `Vector{Float64}`, but I understand that this is what you wanted. If not then in order to convert a matrix into a vector you can call `vec` function on it after reading the data in.

#### EDIT

This is how you can read back a `Matrix` using CSV.jl:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(rand(2,3))
2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1        │ x2       │ x3       │
│     │ Float64   │ Float64  │ Float64  │
├─────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.0444818 │ 0.570981 │ 0.608709 │
│ 2   │ 0.47577   │ 0.675344 │ 0.500577 │

julia> CSV.write("test.csv", df)
"test.csv"

julia> CSV.File("test.csv") |> Tables.matrix
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0444818  0.570981  0.608709
 0.47577    0.675344  0.500577
```

Comment: Perhaps a more straightforward example:  
```
using DelimitedFiles
mat = readdlm("data.csv", ',')
```

Comment: Right, I wanted the initial example to be reproducible without writing anything to disk.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your `DataFrame` to a `Matrix` of a certain type. If there is no missing data this should work. If there is missing data, simply omit the type in `convert`.

`arr = convert(Matrix{Float64}, df)`

You can call `vec` on the result to get a vector if that is really what you want.

Depending on the file, I would go with `readdlm` as suggested in the previous answer.

Comment: This approach is also nice, note that you even can simply write `Matrix{Float64}(df)`.

Comment: Unfortunate that CSV can't directly create an array as its output without first going through a dataframe. I think CSV is Julia's fastest csv reader, but not necessarily the fastest way to produce an array. Producing an array is a common scenario.

Comment: I have added an *EDIT* in my answer to show you how you can get a `Matrix` without an intermediate `DataFrame`.

Comment: You could just take the output of a CSV.File (a CSV rows object) and use as input to Matrix() constructor. Which is exactly what the pipe version does. Curious about the performance of the CSV Rows object, which is an array of named tuples. Named Tuples aren't speed demons, I've found. Seems like we should just port the nice speed improvements of CSV's parsing into readdlm.  Then we'd have 2 very nice fast approaches: one leaning to supporting arrays and the other leaning to supporting DFs. Both are desirable.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize Bogumil's answer, your can use:

```
using DelimitedFiles
data = readdlm("data.csv", ',', Float64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask [`CSV.read`](https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/reading.html#Reading) to use a `Matrix` as its destination in one go with:

```
julia> import CSV

julia> s = """
       1,2,3
       4,5,6
       7,8,9""";

julia> CSV.read(IOBuffer(s), CSV.Tables.matrix; header=false)
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```

Do note that there's a [currently-outstanding issue](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/1030) to directly use the builtin `Matrix` type itself as the "sink", which would make this slightly more discoverable.